# Static and Dynamic DataSource Model

Tags: ios, swift, enums, model, datasource

I have an app that has a 'post detail' `UIViewController`, like most apps this post has comments. My `UIViewController` uses the first cell for the post and then I will load the comments with a separate function filling the rest of the cells with this dynamic content.

I currently have a model as per the below;

```
enum DetailItem {
    case post(post: Post)
    case comments(comments: [Comment]?)
}

struct DetailSection {
    var header: String?
    var footer: String?
    var items: [DetailItem]
    
    init(header: String?, footer: String?, items: [DetailItem]) {
        self.header = header
        self.footer = footer
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

In my UIViewController I initialise the DetailSection as such;

```
    sections = [DetailSection(header: nil, footer: nil, items: [.post(post: post)]),
                DetailSection(header: nil, footer: nil, items: [.comments(comments: comments)])]
```

My question is how can I use this model to add comments to the comments inside `DetailItem`

### UPDATE

Adding datasource methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.item] {
        case .post(post: let post):
            let detailCell = mainView.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DetailCell.identifier,
                                                                         for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
            detailCell.post = post
            return detailCell
        case .comments:
            let commentCell = mainView.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CommentCell.identifier,
                                                                          for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
            commentCell.backgroundColor = .red
            return commentCell
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to pass in an array of comments like I passed in the post but when I call numberOfItemsInSection it returns 1 for that section not the array of comments.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've added my datasource methods to the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've updated my question for how I implement the comment section. As you can see it only considers the enum object (which is count of 1, the .comments reference) not the comment array which I need to use.

Comment: Yeah well now you have changed your model so my previous comments are irrelevant. I am not sure I understand the model any longer